# dotnet core localization does not work on linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have created .net core 2.2 mvc application. also added localization 
it works fine on my local windows machine, but after deployment to linux, localization  does not work. what am I missing ?

Comment: Can you create a minimal repeatable version of the application and share that? For example, if you started with a completely new code base and add localisation to it, then run it on your Linux machine, does your problem persist? Also, which distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: I will try it now.  Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Comment: I have created simple app exactly with same configuration. It works on Linux too. @JamieTaylor Thanks for advise. Now I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my app.

Comment: No worries. I'd suggest trying to remove parts of your app until it starts working again, then take a look at what you've removed. Unless you can go into specifics about what your app is doing (if so, please edit your question to include them)